# REstore only triggers postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I made a backup of a database of postgres, it is not the first time I do it, I used this command:

```
pg_dump db -f /backup/agosto_31.sql
```

And I do the restore with this:

```
psql -d August_31 -f August_31.sql
```

But this time I did not import any trigger, and there are many. I checked in the file August_31.sql and they are. How could I import them again? Only the triggers.

Thanks everyone, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

There are not any possibility to import only triggers. But, because your dump (backup file) is in SQL format (plain text), you can cut trigger definition manually in any editor. For this case is practical dump data and schema to separate files.

Is possible so import (restore from backup) fails, probably due broken dependencies. Check `psql` output if there are some errors. `psql` has nice possibility to stop on first error:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

Use this option. Without error specification is not possible to help more.